# Where might one ask a speculative "off-topic" question?

Tags: discussion

Just that. Can someone recommend some other sites, not part of SE?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That's a bit vague of a question.

Given that, we have [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) and elsewhere there is closely related [Scientific-Speculation](https://scientific-speculation.codidact.com/).